# Why does this text input bleed outside of the div and how do I correct it?

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stpra123/7cap7o7s/7/

`#my_input` flows outside of the cell. I need `#my_input` to fill up the entire width - no more, no less. (Setting `#my_input`'s width to something less than 100% could correct the issue but on some screen sizes but depending on the screen size it doesn't guarantee that it will always line up well). Is there another way to make `#my_input` fit better?

HTML

```
<div class="site-body">
    <div class="site-center">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="col width-fill">
                <div class="container">
                    <form>
                        <input id="my_input" value="I am a bit messed up!" />
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="col width-fill text">
                This is some text that goes directly below #my_input and the widths need to match otherwise
                everything kind of looks funny. 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cell{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#my_input{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.fa-calendar{
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    top: 18px;
}
```

Comment: @CBroe: You don't have to be condescending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add box-sizing:border-box on the input:

```
#my_input{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

And it will not go outside.